# Preserving aspect ratio in a batch with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, batch-processing

I have a large list of images (all different sizes and aspect ratios) that need to be edited. I need to perform the following operations:

1. Crop image to a specific aspect ratio
2. Resize that image to specific dimensions
3. Save/Compress

I tried to create an action, and perform the previous steps. The problem is, even though in the crop tool I would enter my desired aspect ratio, the action wouldn't save that ratio - it would save the actual dimensions it was cropped to. This obviously led to many odd photos being created.

How does one create an action that will preserve aspect ratio across the batch, regardless of image size?

Comment: Instead of cropping, you can change the canvas size of your image based on percentage. **Image > Canvas Size** then change the pixels drop down to percentage.

Comment: @ckpepper02 - Thanks, but this won't work due to the fact that each image is a different size and aspect ratio

Answer (score 2):

I've always used:  `File / Scripts / Image Processor`

[image: Image Processor]

Set your intended size and file type.

Under `#4 Preferences`, Run an `Action` that changes the `Canvas size` to trim your image.
If you want you can add a `Save As Web` event to your Action to optimize it.

See crystalpulse's answer for compression.

I generally change the file (#3) to a square, ie `300px by 300px`, then trim as needed with the `Canvas Size` Action to trim to say `150px by 300px`.

If your Aspect Ratios are vastly different, you might want to make separate batches to process, one for Vertical images, one for Horizontal images using different Actions to change the Canvas Size.

Answer (score 1):

`File > Automate > Fit Image`

Use this to make the image scale to say `1600px x 1600px` or whatever your requirements are.

So your action will something like... `Crop Tool > Set aspect ratio > Crop > Fit Image`. Then set that up in the Batch function, add the `Save To.. Folder` and Close.

As for the compress part. This might need some help outside of Photoshop.

You want an application called 'Hazel', with this you can specify things like: If there is an Uncompressed folder in 'x' folder, then compress it OR If there are files in 'x' folder, compress them and move the compressed file to 'x'.